# jQuery counting spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gretings, I have a bit complicated issue. I'm appending text to textarea with javascript. My question is - how to count, how many spaces are on the text area location, where the mouse is clicked? I'm appending text like this:

```
 function typeInTextarea(el, newText) {
      var start = el.prop("selectionStart")
      var end = el.prop("selectionEnd")
      var text = el.val()
      var before = text.substring(0, start)
      var after  = text.substring(end, text.length)
      el.val(before + newText + after)
      el[0].selectionStart = el[0].selectionEnd = start + newText.length
      el.focus()
    }

$(".containeris").on("click", function() {
      typeInTextarea($("#html_content"), '<div class="container">\n\n</div>')
      return false
    })
```

So the problem is, it starts appending text exactly, where mouse is clicked, but i want to make sure, that closing div, which is being printed in new line, would have same number of spaces in front of it as starting line, to keep indentation. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simpy to count tabulations as symbols.